# C isn't that hard: void ( *( *f[] ) () ) ()

Tags: c, parsing, pointers, function-pointers, void-pointers

I just saw a picture today and think I'd appreciate explanations. So here is the picture:

[image: some c code]

Transcription: "*C isn't that hard: `void (*(*f[])())()` defines `f` as an array of unspecified size, of pointers to functions that return pointers to functions that return `void`.*"

I found this confusing and wondered if such code is ever practical. I googled the picture and found another picture in [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammerHumor/comments/3yfpub/c_isnt_that_hard/cyd5f8d) reddit entry, and here is that picture:

[image: some interesting explanation]

Transcription: "*So the symbols can be read: `f [] * () * () void`. `f` is an array of pointers that take no argument and return a pointer that takes no argument and returns `void`*".

So this "reading spirally" is something valid? Is this how C compilers parse?
It'd be great if there are simpler explanations for this weird code.
Apart from all, can this kind of code be useful? If so, where and when?

There is [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3707096/spiral-rule-and-declaration-follows-usage-for-parsing-c-and-c-declarations) about "spiral rule", but I'm not just asking about how it's applied or how expressions are read with that rule. I'm questioning usage of such expressions and spiral rule's validity as well. Regarding these, some nice answers are already posted.

Comment: The syntax for declarations is intended to be equivalent to the syntax for expressions. You can just look up "operator precedence in C". Or read the standard.

Comment: How could the explanation be simpler?  It covers all aspects of the definition of f w/ a couple of words for each key point.

Comment: Maybe C is hard? That actually declares `f` as an array of pointers to functions that could take any argument .. if it were `void (*(*f[])(void))(void);`, then yes, it would be functions that take no arguments ...

Comment: @ScottHunter You have a point, it sounds pretty clear but somehow still confuses me. Maybe it's because I can't think of any usage of that code.

Comment: In practice, don't code such obscure code. [Use typedef for signatures](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9143434/841108)

Comment: any declaration involving function pointers can be hard. That doesn't mean that normal C or C++ is hard in that same way. Other languages solve this in different ways including not having function pointers, which can be a significant omission in some cases

Comment: One has to admit... Compilers are deterministic state machines unambiguously producing code, the only part that gets confused is the human reading C. Happy new year.

Comment: If you squint your eyes, it looks like LISP.

Comment: If all else fails, there is always http://cdecl.org/ ...

Comment: Read [my question](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/117024) and this will become crystal clear.

Comment: @Mehrdad That's one of those great questions that raises a lot of other questions and pushes you to keep learning. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: @txtechhelp Isn't that ages old interpretation deprecated yet?

Comment: @FISOCPP, well it's actually a language construct (not interpretation). `void test();` declares a function that takes an unspecified (not variadic) number of arguments. The C11 standard says it's an `obsolescent feature`, which means that the compiler implementation can still accept that code but your program won't be a `strictly conforming C program`. So, code like this: `int test(); int main() { int i; i = test(); return i; } int test(int x, int y, int z) { return x*y*z; }` will compile without error (and no warnings), it just won't be strictly conforming, and give fun results back :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the meaning of this piece of code? void (\*signal(int sig, void (\*func)(int)))(int);](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706704/whats-the-meaning-of-this-piece-of-code-void-signalint-sig-void-funcin)

Comment: Read also [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30345939/4265352).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does \`((void (\*)())0x1000)();\` mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30345445/what-does-void-0x1000-mean)

Comment: All languages have their quirks. While the Clockwise/Spiral rule of C is really weird (until you "understand" it), it's interesting to note that the designers of Go, while _thoroughly rejecting_ this often unreadable and error-prone and confusing and needlessly complex (okay I'm kidding, sorta) style of declaration, also called it ["an unusual and clever approach"](http://blog.golang.org/gos-declaration-syntax).

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this?

Comment: @szczurcio A friend posted it on facebook, I don't know where he got this from.

Comment: holy crap... i've been thinking i'm quite good at C ( at least my grades in university told me so ). But this is insane ;)

Answer (score 120, accepted):

There is a rule called the ["Clockwise/Spiral Rule"](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html) to help find the meaning of a complex declaration.

From [c-faq](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html):

> There are three simple steps to follow:
>
> 1. Starting with the unknown element, move in a spiral/clockwise direction; when ecountering the following elements replace them with the corresponding english statements:
>
>    `[X]` or `[]`
>      => Array X size of... or Array undefined size of...
>
>    `(type1, type2)`
>      => function passing type1 and type2 returning...
>
>    `*`
>      => pointer(s) to...
> 2. Keep doing this in a spiral/clockwise direction until all tokens have been covered.
> 3. Always resolve anything in parenthesis first!

You can check the link above for examples.

Also note that to help you there is also a website called:

http://www.cdecl.org

You can enter a C declaration and it will give its english meaning. For

```
void (*(*f[])())()
```

it outputs:

> declare f as array of pointer to function returning pointer to function returning void

**EDIT:**

As pointed out in the comments by [Random832](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691884/random832), the spiral rule does not address array of arrays and will lead to a wrong result in (most of) those declarations. For example for `int **x[1][2];` the spiral rule ignores the fact that `[]` has higher precedence over `*`.

When in front of array of arrays, one can first add explicit parentheses before applying the spiral rule. For example: `int **x[1][2];` is the same as `int **(x[1][2]);` (also valid C) due to precedence and the spiral rule then correctly reads it as "x is an array 1 of array 2 of pointer to pointer to int" which is the correct english declaration.

Note that this issue has also been covered in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16260417/the-spiral-rule-about-declarations-when-is-it-in-error/16265389#16265389) by [James Kanze](https://stackoverflow.com/users/649665/james-kanze) (pointed out by [haccks](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2455888/haccks) in the comments).

Comment: I wish cdecl.org was better

Comment: There is no "spiral rule"... "int ***foo[][][]" defines an array of arrays of arrays of pointers to pointers to pointers. The "spiral" only comes from the fact that this declaration happened to group things in parentheses in a way that caused them to alternate. It's everything on the right, then left, within each set of parentheses.

Comment: @Random832 There is a "spiral rule", and it covers the case you just mentioned, i.e. talks about how to deal with parenthesis/arrays etc. Of course is not a Standard C rule, but a good mnemonic for figuring out how to deal with complicated declarations. IMHO, it is extremely useful and saves you when in trouble or when [cdecl.org](http://cdecl.org/) cannot parse the declaration. Of course one shouldn't abuse such declarations, but it's good to know how they are parsed.

Comment: @vsoftco But it's not "moving in a spiral/clockwise direction" if you only turn around when you reach the parentheses.

Comment: ouah, you should mention that [spiral rule is not universal](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16265389/2455888).

Comment: This spiral rule us just a shortcut that tries to gloss over order of precedence.  You could say that it works "most of the time", but that's not really well-defined.

Comment: Not a rule but a technique.

Comment: It seems like the group of three square brackets defining the three-dimensional array is one node along the spiral path, and then the next node is the group of pointer-to-pointer-to-pointer operators.  So, the spiral rule seems to hold in this case, too.  BTW, it doesn't have to be clockwise.  Everywhere you go clockwise you get the same result if you go counter-clockwise, too.

Answer (score 118):

The "spiral" rule kind of falls out of the following precedence rules:

```
T *a[]    -- a is an array of pointer to T
T (*a)[]  -- a is a pointer to an array of T
T *f()    -- f is a function returning a pointer to T
T (*f)()  -- f is a pointer to a function returning T
```

The subscript `[]` and function call `()` operators have higher precedence than unary `*`, so `*f()` is parsed as `*(f())` and `*a[]` is parsed as `*(a[])`.

So if you want a pointer to an array or a pointer to a function, then you need to explicitly group the `*` with the identifier, as in `(*a)[]` or `(*f)()`.

Then you realize that `a` and `f` can be more complicated expressions than just identifiers; in `T (*a)[N]`, `a` could be a simple identifier, or it could be a function call like `(*f())[N]` (`a` -> `f()`), or it could be an array like `(*p[M])[N]`, (`a` -> `p[M]`), or it could be an array of pointers to functions  like `(*(*p[M])())[N]` (`a` -> `(*p[M])()`), etc.

It would be nice if the indirection operator `*` was postfix instead of unary, which would make declarations somewhat easier to read from left to right (`void f[]*()*();` definitely flows better than `void (*(*f[])())()`), but it's not.

When you come across a hairy declaration like that, start by finding the *leftmost* identifier and apply the precedence rules above, recursively applying them to any function parameters:

```
         f              -- f
         f[]            -- is an array
        *f[]            -- of pointers  ([] has higher precedence than *)
       (*f[])()         -- to functions
      *(*f[])()         -- returning pointers
     (*(*f[])())()      -- to functions
void (*(*f[])())();     -- returning void
```

The `signal` function in the standard library is probably the type specimen for this kind of insanity:

```
       signal                                       -- signal
       signal(                          )           -- is a function with parameters
       signal(    sig,                  )           --    sig
       signal(int sig,                  )           --    which is an int and
       signal(int sig,        func      )           --    func
       signal(int sig,       *func      )           --    which is a pointer
       signal(int sig,      (*func)(int))           --    to a function taking an int                                           
       signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))           --    returning void
      *signal(int sig, void (*func)(int))           -- returning a pointer
     (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int)     -- to a function taking an int
void (*signal(int sig, void (*func)(int)))(int);    -- and returning void
```

At this point most people say "use typedefs", which is certainly an option:

```
typedef void outerfunc(void);
typedef outerfunc *innerfunc(void);

innerfunc *f[N];
```

But...

How would you *use* `f` in an expression? You know it's an array of pointers, but how do you use it to execute the correct function?  You have to go over the typedefs and puzzle out the correct syntax.  By contrast, the "naked" version is pretty eyestabby, but it tells you exactly how to *use* `f` in an expression (namely, `(*(*f[i])())();`, assuming neither function takes arguments).

Comment: Thanks for giving the example of 'signal', showing that these kinds of things do appear in the wild.

Comment: I liked your `f` deceleration tree, explaining the precedence...for some reason I always get a kick out of ASCII-art, especially when it comes to explaining things :)

Comment: *assuming neither function takes arguments*: then you have to use `void` in functions parenthesis, otherwise it can take any arguments.

Comment: @haccks: for the declaration, yes; I was talking about the function call.

Answer (score 65):

In C, declaration mirrors usage—that’s how it’s defined in the standard. The declaration:

```
void (*(*f[])())()
```

Is an assertion that the expression `(*(*f[i])())()` produces a result of type `void`. Which means:

- `f` must be an array, since you can index it:

  ```
  f[i]
  ```
- The elements of `f` must be pointers, since you can dereference them:

  ```
  *f[i]
  ```
- Those pointers must be pointers to functions taking no arguments, since you can call them:

  ```
  (*f[i])()
  ```
- The results of those functions must also be pointers, since you can dereference them:

  ```
  *(*f[i])()
  ```
- Those pointers must *also* be pointers to functions taking no arguments, since you can call them:

  ```
  (*(*f[i])())()
  ```
- Those function pointers must return `void`

The “spiral rule” is just a mnemonic that provides a different way of understanding the same thing.

Comment: Great way of looking at it that I've never seen before. +1

Comment: Nice. Seen this way, it _really is simple_. Actually rather easier than something like `vector< function<function<void()>()>* > f`, especially if you add in the `std::`s. (But well, the example _is_ contrived... even `f :: [IORef (IO (IO ()))]` looks weird.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! With the `f[i]` written this definitely makes sense to me, but I don't see why this original part of the code `(*f[])()` is valid. Isn't it a call to a function of the array without defining which element to choose?

Comment: @TimoDenk: The declaration `a[x]` indicates that the expression `a[i]` is valid when `i >= 0 && i < x`. Whereas, `a[]` leaves the size unspecified, and is therefore identical to `*a`: it indicates that the expression `a[i]` (or equivalently `*(a + i)`) is valid for *some* range of `i`.

Comment: This is by far the easiest way to think about C types, thanks for this

Comment: I love this! Much easier to reason about than silly spirals. `(*f[])()` is a type you can index, then dereference, then call, so it's an array of pointers to functions.

Answer (score 42):

> So this "reading spirally" is something valid?

Applying spiral rule or using [cdecl](http://www.cdecl.org/) are not valid always. Both fails in some cases. Spiral rule works for many cases, but [it is not universal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16265389/2455888).

To decipher complex declarations remember these two simple rules:

- **Always read declarations from inside out**: Start from innermost, if any, parenthesis. Locate the identifier that's being declared, and start deciphering the declaration from there.
- **When there is a choice, always favour `[]` and `()` over `*`**: If `*` precedes the identifier and `[]` follows it, the identifier represents an array, not a pointer. Likewise, if `*` precedes the identifier and `()` follows it, the identifier represents a function, not a pointer. (Parentheses can always be used to override the normal priority of `[]` and `()` over `*`.)

This rule actually involves **zigzagging** from one side of the identifier to the other.

Now deciphering a simple declaration

```
int *a[10];
```

Applying rule:

```
int *a[10];      "a is"  
     ^  

int *a[10];      "a is an array"  
      ^^^^ 

int *a[10];      "a is an array of pointers"
    ^

int *a[10];      "a is an array of pointers to `int`".  
^^^
```

Let's decipher the complex declaration like

```
void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();
```

by applying the above rules:

```
void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is"  
          ^  

void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is an array"  
           ^^ 

void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is an array of pointers" 
         ^    

void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is an array of pointers to function"   
               ^^     

void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is an array of pointers to function returning pointer"
       ^   

void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is an array of pointers to function returning pointer to function" 
                    ^^    

void ( *(*f[]) () ) ();        "f is an array of pointers to function returning pointer to function returning `void`"  
^^^^
```

Here is a GIF demonstrating how you go (click on image for larger view):

[image]

---

<sub>The rules mentioned here is taken from the book [C Programming A Modern Approach by K.N KING](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0393979504).</sub>

Comment: This is just like the standard's approach i.e. "declaration mirrors usage". I'd like to ask something else at this point though: Do you suggest K. N. King's book? I'm seeing lots of nice reviews about the book.

Comment: Yeah. I do suggest that book. I started programming from that book. Good texts and problems in there.

Comment: Can you provide an example of cdecl failing to understand a declaration? I thought cdecl used the same parsing rules as compilers, and as far as I can tell it always works.

Comment: @FabioTurati; A function can't return arrays or function. `char (x())[5]` should result in syntax error but, cdecl parse it as: *declare `x` as function returning array 5 of `char`*.

Answer (score 12):

It's only a "spiral" because there happens to be, in this declaration, only one operator on each side within each level of parentheses. Claiming that you proceed "in a spiral" generally would suggest you alternate between arrays and pointers in the declaration `int ***foo[][][]` when in reality all of the array levels come before any of the pointer levels.

Comment: Well, in the "spiral approach", you go as far right as you can, then as far left as you can, etc. But it's often explained erroneously...

Answer (score 7):

I doubt constructions like this can have any use in real life. I even detest them as interview questions for the regular developers (likely OK for compiler writers). typedefs should be used instead.

Comment: Nonetheless, it's important to know how to parse it, even if only to know how to parse the typedef!

Comment: @inetknght, the way you do it with typedefs is to have them simple enough so that no parsing would be required.

Comment: People who ask these types of questions during interviews only do it to stroke their Egos.

Comment: I have used constructs similar to this in production code; I had a lookup table of parsing functions keyed by elements of a file name and a function to search that table and return the right parsing function.  The prototype was something like `void (*getParser(const char *ftype, const char *ext))(const char *fname);`.

Comment: @JohnBode, and you would do yourself a favor by typedefing return value of the function.

Comment: @SergeyA: As I said in my answer, `typedef`s hide information (that's kind of their point); the "naked" form tells me *exactly* how `getParser` is to be used in an expression, and how its return value should be used as well.  If this was some ADT that I just passed around in an API (like the `FILE` type), then a `typedef` is the right answer.  Given that I have to actually *call* the function, it's better to have that information explcitily available in the prototype.

Comment: @JohnBode, i find it a matter of personal choice not worth debating. I see your preference, I still have mine.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thank god this is an answer and we can up vote against the madness of using this type of obfuscation . @JohnBode using typedefs is the way to avoid people coming at your desk an hitting you with a hammer. Otherwise your answer above is perfect.

Answer (score 7):

As a random trivia factoid, you might find it amusing to know that there's an actual word in English to describe how C declarations are read: [Boustrophedonically](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boustrophedon), that is, alternating right-to-left with left-to-right.

Reference: [Van der Linden, 1994](https://books.google.com/books?id=4vm2xK3yn34C&redir_esc=y) - [Page 76](http://img.blog.csdn.net/20130710135832062)

Comment: That word doesn't indicate *within* as in nested by parens or on a single line. It describes a "snake" pattern, with an LTR line followed by an RTL line.

Answer (score 5):

Regarding the usefulness of this, when working with shellcode you see this construct a lot:

```
int (*ret)() = (int(*)())code;
ret();
```

While not quite as syntactically complicated, this particular pattern comes up a lot.

More complete example in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16626857/shellcode-in-c-program) SO question.

So while the usefulness to the extent in the original picture is questionable (I would suggest that any production code should be drastically simplified), there are some syntactical constructs that do come up quite a bit.

Answer (score 5):

The declaration

```
void (*(*f[])())()
```

is just an obscure way of saying

```
Function f[]
```

with

```
typedef void (*ResultFunction)();

typedef ResultFunction (*Function)();
```

In practice, more descriptive names will be needed instead of *ResultFunction* and *Function*. If possible I would also specify the parameter lists as `void`.

Answer (score 5):

I happen to be the original author of the spiral rule that I wrote oh so many years ago (when I had a lot of hair :) and was honored when it was added to the cfaq.

I wrote the spiral rule as a way to make it easier for my students and colleagues to read the C declarations "in their head"; i.e., without having to use software tools like cdecl.org, etc. It was never my intent to declare  that the spiral rule be the canonical way to parse C expressions.  I am though, delighted to see that the rule has helped literally thousands of C programming students and practitioners over the years!

For the record,

It has been "correctly" identified numerous times on many sites, including by Linus Torvalds (someone whom I respect immensely), that there are situations where my spiral rule "breaks down". The most common being:

```
char *ar[10][10];
```

As pointed out by others in this thread, the rule could be updated to say that when you encounter arrays, simply consume all the indexes *as if* written like:

```
char *(ar[10][10]);
```

Now, following the spiral rule, I would get:

"ar is a 10x10 two-dimensional array of pointers to char"

I hope the spiral rule carries on its usefulness in learning C!

P.S.:

I love the "C isn't hard" image :)

Answer (score 4):

> Remember these rules for C declares
>   And precedence never will be in doubt:
>   Start with the suffix, proceed with the prefix,
>   And read both sets from the inside, out.
>   -- me, mid-1980's

Except as modified by parentheses, of course. And note that the syntax for declaring these exactly mirrors the syntax for using that variable to get an instance of the base class.

Seriously, this isn't hard to learn to do at a glance; you just have to be willing to spend some time practising the skill. If you're going to maintain or adapt C code written by other people, it's *definitely* worth investing that time. It's also a fun party trick for freaking out other programmers who haven't learned it.

For your own code: as always, the fact that something *can* be written as a one-liner does't mean it should be, unless it is an extremely common pattern that has become a standard idiom (such as the string-copy loop). You, and those who follow you, will be *much* happier if you build complex types out of layered typedefs and step-by-step dereferences rather than relying on your ability to generate and parse these "at one swell foop." Performance will be just as good, and code readability and maintainability will be tremendously better.

It could be worse, you know. There was a legal PL/I statement that started with something like:

```
if if if = then then then = else else else = if then ...
```

Comment: The PL/I statement was `IF IF = THEN THEN THEN = ELSE ELSE ELSE = ENDIF ENDIF` and is parsed as `if (IF == THEN) then (THEN = ELSE) else (ELSE = ENDIF)`.

Comment: I _think_ there was a version which took it one step farther by using a conditional IF/THEN/ ELSE expression (equivalent to C's ?:), which got the third set into the mix... but it's been a few decades and may have depended upon a particular dialect of the language. Point remains that any language has at least one pathological form.

Answer (score 4):

I found method described by Bruce Eckel to be helpful and easy to follow:

> **Defining a function pointer**
>
> To define a pointer to a function that has no arguments and no return
>   value, you say:
>
> `void (*funcPtr)();`
>
> **When you are looking at a complex definition like
>   this, the best way to attack it is to start in the middle and work
>   your way out.** “Starting in the middle” means starting at the variable
>   name, which is funcPtr. “Working your way out” means looking to the
>   right for the nearest item (nothing in this case; the right
>   parenthesis stops you short), then looking to the left (a pointer
>   denoted by the asterisk), then looking to the right (an empty argument
>   list indicating a function that takes no arguments), then looking to
>   the left (void, which indicates the function has no return value).
>   This right-left-right motion works with most declarations.
>
> To review, “start in the middle” (“funcPtr is a ...”), go to the right
>   (nothing there – you're stopped by the right parenthesis), go to the
>   left and find the ‘*’ (“... pointer to a ...”), go to the right and
>   find the empty argument list (“... function that takes no arguments
>   ... ”), go to the left and find the void (“funcPtr is a pointer to a
>   function that takes no arguments and returns void”).
>
> You may wonder why *funcPtr requires parentheses. If you didn't use
>   them, the compiler would see:
>
> `void *funcPtr();`
>
> You would be declaring a function (that returns a
>   void*) rather than defining a variable. You can think of the compiler
>   as going through the same process you do when it figures out what a
>   declaration or definition is supposed to be. It needs those
>   parentheses to “bump up against” so it goes back to the left and finds
>   the ‘*’, instead of continuing to the right and finding the empty
>   argument list.
>
> **Complicated declarations & definitions**
>
> As an aside, once you figure out how the C and C++ declaration syntax
>   works you can create much more complicated items. For instance:
>
> ```
> //: C03:ComplicatedDefinitions.cpp
>
> /* 1. */     void * (*(*fp1)(int))[10];
>
> /* 2. */     float (*(*fp2)(int,int,float))(int);
>
> /* 3. */     typedef double (*(*(*fp3)())[10])();
>              fp3 a;
>
> /* 4. */     int (*(*f4())[10])();
>
>
> int main() {} ///:~
> ```
>
> Walk through each one and use the right-left
>   guideline to figure it out. **Number 1** says “fp1 is a pointer to a
>   function that takes an integer argument and returns a pointer to an
>   array of 10 void pointers.”
>
> **Number 2** says “fp2 is a pointer to a function that takes three
>   arguments (int, int, and float) and returns a pointer to a function
>   that takes an integer argument and returns a float.”
>
> If you are creating a lot of complicated definitions, you might want
>   to use a typedef. **Number 3** shows how a typedef saves typing the
>   complicated description every time. It says “An fp3 is a pointer to a
>   function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to an array of
>   10 pointers to functions that take no arguments and return doubles.”
>   Then it says “a is one of these fp3 types.” typedef is generally
>   useful for building complicated descriptions from simple ones.
>
> **Number 4** is a function declaration instead of a variable definition.
>   It says “f4 is a function that returns a pointer to an array of 10
>   pointers to functions that return integers.”
>
> You will rarely if ever need such complicated declarations and
>   definitions as these. However, if you go through the exercise of
>   figuring them out you will not even be mildly disturbed with the
>   slightly complicated ones you may encounter in real life.

[Taken from: Thinking in C++ Volume 1, second edition, chapter 3, section "Function Addresses" by Bruce Eckel.](http://www.drbio.cornell.edu/pl47/programming/TICPP-2nd-ed-Vol-one-html/Frames.html)

Answer (score 3):

- void `(*(*f[]) ()) ()`

Resolving `void` >>

- `(*(*f[]) ())` ()  = void

Resoiving `()` >>

- (*`(*f[]) ()`) = function returning (void)

Resolving `*` >>

- `(*f[])` () = pointer to (function returning (void) )

Resolving `()` >>

- (*`f[]`) = function returning (pointer to (function returning (void)   ))

Resolving `*` >>

- `f`[] = pointer to (function returning (pointer to (function returning
  (void) )))

Resolving `[ ]` >>

- **f = array of (pointer to (function returning (pointer to (function
  returning (void) ))))**