# What this declaration "float (*x[20])(int *a)" means?

Tags: c++, c

I found somewhere this weird variable declaration -

```
float (*x[20])(int *a);
```

What could it possibly mean?
What is the purpose of it?

Comment: It's a dumber way of writing `typedef float func_t (int* a);` then declare `func_t* array[20];`

Answer (score 12):

`float (*x[20])(*int a)` is not correct. It should be `float (*x[20])(int *a)` which declares `x` as an array of 20 pointers to a function that takes an argument of `int *` type and returns `float`.

---

For those who are curious to know the [use](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23903167/2455888) of an array of function pointers:

```
typedef double Func(double, double);          // Declare a double (double, double)

Func sum, subtract, mul, divide;              // Function prototypes.
Func *p[] = { sum, subtract, mul, divide };   // Array of function pointers

int main(void)
{
    double result;
    double a, b;
    int option;
    printf("This is a simple calculator to add, subtract, multiply and divideide two integers\n"); 
    printf("Enter two integers: ");
    scanf("%lf %lf", &a, &b);

    printf("Choose an option:\n 1. Add\n 2. Subtract\n 3. Mult\n 4. Divide\n");
    scanf("%d", &option);

    result = p[option - 1](a, b); 
    printf("result = %lf\n", result);
}

double sum(double a, double b) { return a+b; }
double subtract(double a, double b) { return a-b; }
double mul(double a, double b) { return a*b; }
double divide(double a, double b) { return a/b; }
```

---

A detailed explanation on how to read/decipher such complex declaration is discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560439/2455888).

Comment: is there any reason one should do that? I dont see anything this could be useful for.

Comment: @Flikk; I added one simple use of array of function pointers.

Comment: @haccks Thx, that makes sense. i haven't worked with function pointers so far. How would it look like with the syntax from the question though? I guess something like `double (*p[ ])(double a, double b) = { sum, subtract, mul, divide };`. What else would this syntax need? The function prototypes? and anything else?

Comment: @Flikk; Smarter way to write `double (*p[ ])(double a, double b) = { sum, subtract, mul, divide };` is `typedef double Func(double, double); Func *p[] = { sum, subtract, mul, divide };`

Comment: @haccks so if i don't have the typedef, i have to declare the prototypes like `double sum(double, double);
double subtract(double, double);
double mul(double, double);
double divide(double, double);` or is there any way to write it shorter without the typedef?

Comment: @Flikk; Yes. Having typedef, shorter version is `Func sum, subtract, mul, divide;`

Comment: Any reason why you have `main` returning a `double`?

Comment: @dbush actually I don't remember if I did that intentionally or accidentally. BTW, fixed that now.

Answer (score 1):

this is an array of function pointers. it has 20 function pointer items.

Answer (score 1):

The declaration

```
float (*x[20])(int *a);
```

defines the variable *x* as an array of 20 functions (function pointers). In my humble opinion it's more clearly written as

```
Function x[20];
```

with

```
typedef float (*Function)(int *a);
```

The purpose of *x* is hard to tell without context, it could be to compute a statistical value like average, variance or standard deviation etc. given a set of integers and a function index input by the user:

```
x[0] = Average;
x[1] = Variance;
x[2] = StandardDeviation;
...

int a[100];
int i;

/*read data into `a' and function index into i...*/

printf("%f\n", x[i](a));
```

Answer (score 0):

The code should be like this: - `float (*x[20])(int *a);` - as `(*int a)` seems to be incorrect. The code tells me that x is an array of 20 pointers to function that each takes an argument with datatype int and return float.