# What does the input argument type "const double *&" mean?

Tags: c++, constants, pass-by-reference

Consider the following code:

```
void func1(const double& x) {
    x = 1.2; //compilation error! (assignment of read-only reference)
}
void func2(const double* x) {
    *x = 1.3; //compilation error! (assignment of read-only location)
}
void func3(const double*& x) {
    *x = 1.4; //compilation error! (assignment of read-only location)
}
int main()
{
    double a = 1.1;
    func1(a);
    double *y = &a;
    func2(y);
    func3(y); //compilation error! (invalid initialization of reference of type 'const double*&' from expression of type 'double*')
    return 0;
}
```

Here, my understanding is that `func1()` takes a reference to a double, and that `func2()` takes a pointer to a double. In both cases, the `const` keyword means that the value of the double can't be modified by the function. Hence, I get compilation errors as expected.

But what's going on with `func3()`? I can't seem to find an explanation for what this input argument type means that would explain the compilation errors. I would assume that `const double*& x` means "a reference to a `double*`, which can't be modified". But this seems to be the wrong interpretation: I can't send in a `double*` (but I CAN send in a `const double*`) and I can modify the address that the pointer points to (but I CAN'T modify the `double` that the pointer points to).

I guess my confusion comes from a misunderstanding of what the `const` keyword is "attached" to: to the `&`? to the `double*`? What is the interpretation of `const double*& x` that would clear up my confusion?

EDIT: This question is distinct from the suggested duplicate because it in large part has to do with how to interpret what the `const` keyword "attaches to".

Comment: `const double*&` means "reference to `const double*`".  You already know what the latter means because you just described it: it means that although the pointer can be modified, the thing pointed-to cannot be.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [void ( \*( \*f\[\] ) () ) ()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762/void-f)

Comment: Also: [cdecl.org](http://www.cdecl.org) is good if one is uncertain about the meaning of a declaration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`const double*&` is a reference to a pointer to a const double. So `*x` is a const double, which you cannot assign thus. `const` is attached to `double` here.

You may want to use either `double* const` (which is a const pointer to [non-const] double) or `double* const&` (which is a reference to a const pointer to [non-const] double).

Answer (score 3):

```
const double*& x
```

means that `x` is a reference to a pointer to a const double, which implies the object can't be modified (i.e. `const` is a type qualifier attached to `double`, not the pointer object itself in this case)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I suspected as much. But what confuses me is that while `const double*&` is a reference to a pointer to a const double, `const double&` is NOT a reference to a const double. How can this be understood? In terms of the clockwise-spiral rule? Something else?

Comment: @andreasdr `const double&` IS a reference to a const double.

Comment: I'm starting to realize what my misunderstanding has been. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`const double*& x`, means a non-const reference to `const double*`.

When you pass a `double*`, it need to be casted to `const double*`, which is a temporary variable and can't be bound to a non-const reference, that's why compiler complains.

BTW: `const double* const & x` is a const reference to `const double*`.

Comment: Thanks, but regarding your last point, isn't that a reference to a const pointer to a const double? Although figuring out what `const` "sticks to" confuses me to no end, that is the interpretation suggested by http://cdecl.org/

Comment: @andreasdr Yes, the precise statement should be "reference to const pointer to const double". Since there's no "non-const reference", which could be rebound to something else after initialized, so we say "const reference" for "reference to const" and "non-const reference" for "reference to non-const". Yes it's confusing...