# What in the syntax rules makes prototypes of functions that return pointers and function pointers different?

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

The prototype for defining a function that returns a pointer looks like this:

```
int * function_name();
```

At the same time, the prototype for a function pointer looks like this:

```
int (*function_name)();
```

What syntax rules makes those two definitions different? How does precedence come into play?

For instance, is

```
(int *) function_name();
```

a prototype for a function that returns a pointer or a pointer function? (My intuition is that it defines a function that return `(int *)`, and hence is the former.)

Edit: I realized that my question is actually about C declarations. A good resource for understanding those is http://unixwiz.net/techtips/reading-cdecl.html

Comment: The syntax of C is clearly not perfect.

Comment: Try a function that returns a function pointer.

Comment: Disambiguation is a nasty business, but it must be done. Fortunately we can use typedefs to alleviate the awkwardness.

Comment: Are you writing a c parser?

Comment: @DeiDei: Wait, so

   `int (*function_name(int n))(int, int);`

is a *function* that returns a *function pointer*? :D

Comment: @IharobAlAsimi: I am trying to figure out if the C syntax is consistent somehow when it comes to defining all those functions. Looks like it isn't.

Comment: Then it's a bad question.

Comment: @Xeneda: Hmmm. So `int function_name();` is a function prototype, and `(int) function_name();` is a function call followed by casting to `int`. Interesting.

Comment: @alpha: I thought you meant when calling the function, I somehow didn't read "is .... a **prototype**

Comment: @haccks: Why? If `function_name` returns, say, a `char *` pointer, cannot you cast it up to an `int *` pointer? (The result will be garbage, but still...)

Comment: @alpha yes http://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28%2afunction_name%28int%29%29%28int%2C+int%29

Comment: @PSkocik: Thanks for cdecl.org, it is awesome!

Comment: @alpha cdecl is also a CLI app. I use typedefs, though (even though I can read C declarations OK, I think typedefs are clearer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(int *) function_name();
```

as a function **prototype** is syntax error.
When calling `function_name();` that way, it **casts** the return value to an `int *`:

```
int main(void) {
  (int *) function_name(); //the return value is being casted to an `int *`
  return 0;
}
```

The following is a function that returns a pointer:

```
int *function_name();
```

And the following is a function pointer, i.e. a pointer to a function:

```
int (*function_name)();
```

Let me cite [this:](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

> Sometimes people get confused when more stars are thrown in:
>   `void *(*foo)(int *);`
>   Here, the key is to read inside-out; notice that the innermost element of the expression is *foo, and that otherwise it looks like a normal function declaration. *foo should refer to a function that returns a void * and takes an int *. Consequently, foo is a pointer to just such a function.

Answer (score 2):

> What syntax rules makes those two definitions different?

The rule for parsing is:

1. Locate the identifier.
2. Always favour `[]` and `()` over `*`.

So, for  `int * function_name();`, identifier `function_name` will goes with `()` instead of `*` and therefore `function_name` is declared as function that returns pointer to `int`.

For `int (*function_name)();`, The extra outer parenthesis force `function_name` to comes with `*` rather than `()`. So, this declares `function_name` as a pointer to function that returns an `int`.

`(int *) function_name();` can't be used outside of a function. Compiler will report a syntax error. Upon seeing `(int *)` compiler will interpret is as a cast operator and `function_name()` as a function call.

---

Further reading: [Deciphering complex declaration like `void ( *( *f[] ) () ) ()`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34560439/2455888).

Comment: `(int *) function_name();` is valid C syntax, but it cannot be used outside of a function body.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so applying the rules of reading C declarations (e.g. [here](http://unixwiz.net/techtips/gnu-c-attributes.html)):

```
int * function_name();
```

declares function_name as a function returning a pointer to `int`, whereas

```
int (* function_name)();
```

declares function_name as a pointer to a function returning `int`.