# School Assignment of understanding the definition of a specific C pointer

Tags: c, pointers, syntax

During a C introductory course (in an Engineering University), we were asked to identify a declaration with pointers along the lines of `int (*(*f[5])(void))[10];`.

my current understanding of the declaration would be "an array containing 10 function pointers returning an int pointer each and not taking any args".

Could someone confirm my understanding of the declaration, and tell me if such definitions would be of any use in practice ?

Comment: I suggest you follow [the clockwise spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html). Starting from the variable (`f` in your case) and go outwards.

Comment: https://cdecl.org/ might also be helpful.

Comment: In practice, not many C programmers would know what this declaration means. If they needed something complicated like this, they'd use typedefs to make it more readable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C isn't that hard: void ( \*( \*f\[\] ) () ) ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762/c-isnt-that-hard-void-f)

Comment: This is a typical school assignment to learn how C declarations work. And when you have learned that, you have also learned never to do this. Except possibly for a code review on April 1.

Answer (score 5):

`int (*(*f[5])(void))[10]` declares `(*(*f[5])(void))[10]` to be an `int`.

Which means `(*(*f[5])(void))` is an array of 10 `int`.

Which means `(*f[5])(void)` is a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.

Which means `(*f[5])` is a function taking `void` and returning a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.

Which means `f[5]` is a pointer to a function taking `void` and returning a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.

Which means `f` is an array of 5 pointers to functions taking `void` and returning a pointer to an array of 10 `int`.