# What is the name of this C function style?

Tags: c, function, gcc, parameters, arguments

I am confused about following C function, f_2(). It is written in .c file, code can be compiled by gcc. What is the name of this function style? How to interpret the meaning of this function? Is this standard C or some gcc extension? Thanks.

```
void f_1()
{
}

int (*f_2(void *param)) (int, void *) {
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
  f_2(NULL);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: So calling `f_2(NULL)` throws away the returned function taking an `int` and a `void *`

Comment: `f1` is called dead code as it is not used ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The function `f_2` takes a `void *` arguments, and returns a pointer to a function.

The pointer that `f_2` returns is a pointer to a function that takes two arguments (an `int` and a `void *`) and returns an `int`.

It's equivalent to:

```
// Create a type-alias for a function pointer
typedef int (*function_pointer_type)(int, void *);

// Define a function that returns a pointer to a function
function_pointer_type f_2(void *)
{
    return NULL;
}
```

Comment: I do not remember ever having used function pointers without `typedef`'ing its type. The notation without typedef is so weird that I imagine it is confusing for most people, even experienced C programmers.

Comment: with C23 one can simply write `typeof(int(int,void*)) * f2(void*)`

Answer (score 3):

Parsing a C definition visually can be done using the spiral rule:

```
int (*f_2(void *param)) (int, void *) {
```

- start for the identifier being defined, here `f_2`:

  *`f_2` is ...*
- read and spell the postfix operators from left to right: `(void *param)`:

  *`f_2` is a function taking a `void *` argument named `param` returning...*
- when you hit an obstacle (`)`, `;`, `,`, `{`...), go back to where you started parsing postfix operators and parse prefix operators right to left: here the is only a `*` so:

  *`f_2` is a function taking a `void *` argument named `param` returning a pointer to a...*
- you have parsed the parenthesized expression, so start again with its postfix and then prefix operators: `(int, void *)`:

  *(`f_2` is a function taking a `void *` argument named `param` returning a pointer to a) function taking an `int` and a `void *` arguments returning...*
- back to the `(` and parse the prefix operators: there is just the `int` return type, so the final phrase is:

  *`f_2` is a function taking a `void *` argument named `param` returning a pointer to a function taking an `int` and a `void *` arguments returning an `int`.*

You may want to read this question and its answers too: [C isn't that hard: void ( *( *f[] ) () ) ()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34548762/c-isnt-that-hard-void-f)

Comment: Upvoted for the detailed explanation of deciphering this declaration. The length and complexity of the explanation makes a strong case for the use of `typedef` to help the poor reader of the code.