# What does int (*ar) [] declaration mean in C?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, variables

What is the difference between these two in C. The first one is array of pointers.
My main confusion is about the second declaration. What does it declare. Aren't the two the same ?

```
int *p []={&i,&j,&k};

int (*ar) [];
```

Comment: Sorry.Edited that out. Thank you.

Comment: ["declare p as array of pointer to int"](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+*p+%5B%5D), ["declare ar as pointer to array of int"](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*ar%29+%5B%5D)

Comment: Take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345939/4265352) on a similar question.

Comment: Array of pointers versus a pointer to an array. Two very different things. The second (pointer to array) will not compile since the array need a size.

Comment: `p` is an array of pointers to ints, initialized with three values (and so the array size is 3). `ar` is a pointer to an array of integers.

Comment: `int (*ar) [];` => `ar` is a pointer to an array of int.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The two are not the same.  The second is a **pointer to an array of `int`**.

You can use such a declaration as a function parameter when passing a 2D array as a parameter.  For example, given this function:

```
void f(int (*ar)[5])    // array size required here to do pointer arithmetic for 2D array
{
    ...
}
```

You could call it like this:

```
int a[5][5];
f(a);
```

Another example as a local parameter:

```
int a[5] = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
int (*ar)[];   // array size not required here since we point to a 1D array
int i;

ar = &a;
for (i=0;i<5;i++) {
    printf("a[%d]=%d\n", i, (*ar)[i]);
}
```

Output:

```
a[0]=1
a[1]=2
a[2]=3
a[3]=4
a[4]=5
```

Comment: Thank you so much, can they be declared and used inside a function( not in the parameter) ? If not then why is there a scope to declare such things inside a function.

Comment: @Neer Yes they can.  See my edit for an example.

Answer (score 6):

Just follow the ["right-left" rule](http://ieng9.ucsd.edu/~cs30x/rt_lt.rule.html)

`int *p []={&i,&j,&k};` // reads: "p is an array of pointers to int"

`int (*ar) [];` // "ar is a pointer to an array of ints"