# Pointer to a function and its return type (void)

Tags: c, function, pointers, void-pointers, return-type

Is such declaration `void *(*function) ()` is valid ?
If it is valid then `*function` will return any address to called function .
At that address, what value is returning? 
Is value save at that address is 0. If it is zero,what is the difference between `return 0` and return nothing in function having return type `void`.

Comment: *"Is such declaration `void *(*function) ()` is valid ?"* -- a compiler gives you the best answer to this question. Yes, it is valid. `function` is a pointer to a function that doesn't get any arguments and returns a void pointer. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30345939/4265352) for a detailed explanation about how to read the C declarations.

Comment: Perhaps a better approach would be to explain _why_ you have these questions, as taken in isolation, they mean almost nothing.

Comment: Badly worded question but the answers are useful

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The declaration is read as follows:

```
        function        -- function is a 
       *function        -- pointer to 
      (*function) ()    -- function taking unspecified parameters
     *(*function) ()    -- returning pointer to
void *(*function) ();   -- void
```

So, `function` is a *pointer* to a function type, not a function itself.  You could have multiple functions, each returning pointers to `void`:

```
void *foo( void )    { ... }
void *bar( void )    { ... }
void *bletch( void ) { ... }
```

You can use the `function` pointer to point to each of those functions, and decide at runtime which to call:

```
if ( condition1 )
  function = foo;
else if ( condition2 )
  function = bar;
else
  function = bletch;

void *ptr = function(); // or (*function)();
```

Answer (score 2):

The notation

```
void * (*function)();
```

means “declare a function pointer named `function`, which points to a function that takes an unspecified number of arguments, then returns a `void *`.”

Since this just declares a variable, it doesn’t define a function and so nothing can be said about what value is going to be returned. You’d need to assign this pointer to point to a function before you can call it.

Once you do assign `function` to point to something, if you call `function`, you’ll get back a `void *`, which you can think of as “a pure memory address” since it contains an address but can’t be dereferenced to an object without a cast.

Notice that returning a `void *` is not the same as as a function that has a `void` return type. The former means “I return a memory address,” and the latter means “I don’t return anything at all.”